# Как создать статический фрагмент яндекс карты?

Tags: python, python-3.x, yandex-maps-api, tilemap

Всем доброго времени суток.
В GUI приложении есть необходимость сохранять фрагмент карты тайлами по заданному прямоугольнику (минимальная широта, минимальная долгота, максимальная широта, максимальная долгота). В данный момент получаю пазлы карт от сервера OpenStreetMap:

```
    #...
    headers = {
        "user-agent" : "MyApp",
        "accept" : "*/*",
        "accept-encoding" : "gzip, deflate",
        "accept-language" : "ru, en"
    }
    response = requests.get(rf'http://{server}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{zoom}/{x}/{y}.png', headers=headers)
    #...
```

Хотелось бы реализовать аналогичный способ получения карты, но используя ресурсы Яндекс.Карт, а не OpenStreetMap. Как это можно сделать? Прочитал API Yandex.Map, но не смог разобраться и найти то, что мне нужно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У Яндекса для этого есть отдельный сервис - [Static API](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/staticapi/?from=mapsapi)
Если вам нужно сохранять карту, вам потребуется коммерческий ключ. Если все-таки планируете использовать бесплатный ключ, убедитесь, что ваше приложение соответствует [условиям бесплатного обслуживания](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/terms/index.html/).